# Recommended tool to generate RDL report files that integrates well with .NET

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, report, xml-namespaces, rdl

I'm looking for recommended tools and your experience with them for generating and viewing RDL (reporting definition language) files that can integrate well with a .NET application.

These are tools I've found so far.  If you've worked with them and can give your experience (good and bad), ease of use, etc.. I'd love to learn.  Our company is trying to choose a product for reporting.

http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/index.epx
http://www.pebblereports.com/
http://gotreportviewer.com/
http://www.fyireporting.com/
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917530.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/rdlproject.aspx

**We need it to work with the 2005 schema at the very least:**

Report Definition Schema

June 2005
Description

This schema describes the structure of the Report Definition Language (RDL), an XML schema for representing reports which includes query, calculation and layout metadata.
Schema for Report Definition Schema

ReportDefinition.xsd

Comment: Telerik has their own reporting system (not RDL) but it's very "pretty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of those tools you've mentioned I've only worked with fyi reporting so I can't offer a comparison. We use the fyi libraries currently to generate reports on Windows mobile 6 devices integrating the fyi libraries with a .net compact framework application.

We also use fyi to generate PDFs from a server side console application built in .net 2.0.

Both have been in production and running without problems for around a year now.

Comment: seems like this type of question is too generic.  :-)  I gave you some points.